# Azure - ingesting data into IoT Hub and sending notifications via slack/email for certain messages

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-iot-hub, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-stream-analytics

I've got data coming into IoTHub and want to filter on them.
Relevant data I want to forward to slack as notification.

I've got the IoT Hub and a slack subscription in place and am having trouble connecting the two.

In order to do a rather complex time-based query, I figure to use Stream Analytics and configure the IoT Hub as input. From research I found Logic Apps can send messages to Slack over a webhook. Using a Service Bus Queue as output for Stream Analytics, I can get the data into Logic Apps.

So it's:

> IoT Hub (ingest all data) => Stream Analytics (filter) => Service Bus Queue (queue up the data) => Logic Apps (send to Slack)

Looks a bit bulky but that seems to be one way of doing it (is there a better one?!?)

Doing this I ran into issues. I selected my IoT Hub as input for Stream Analytics and the simple query `SELECT * INTO [Queue] FROM [Hub]` fails, saying there was no data.

It does make sense if the IoT Hub just pushes new data to its endpoints and then discards it. So I created a test set in the Stream Analytics Job and the query runs fine.

However I do get data into the Hub which is not (all) picked up nor forwarded by the job to the service bus queue. I do see some activity on the queue but not nearly enough to be the data I receive.

This seems to be a very common scenario, ingesting data in IoT Hub and sending notifications to email or slack if they are of a certain type. Can you explain the steps to take or point me to a resource that does it. Maybe I'm on the wrong path as I cannot find anything that describes this.

Thanks

Comment: You have a very large architectural implementation + Troubleshooting +Suggestion Question in one place. I would suggest you to break down your Technical question into multiple small questions, so that the community forum would be able to focus on one issue. Also try [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/25494/azure-iot-hub.html)

Comment: Your implementation looks good, the only point we have to remember is that the data massaging part. Azure IoThub provides the telemetry from IoT Devices and we have to make use of custom logic to do the remaining part i.e ETL kind of stuff. Your flow looks good, the only issue we have here is the missing data from Azure IoTHub, for that i suggest start with small amount of ingested data and monitor the ingress vs egress from Azure IoThub. Please make use of other routes and let us know if you still see data missing. Filter criteria needs to be verified sometimes.